# Speed up loading dynamically generated form/template in AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs, performance, templates, build

I'm generating a form from JSON data that I load via `$http.get()`, hence use bunch of custom/3rd party directives ([ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/), [Bootstrap UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), ...) to get the desired end result. Just to make things more interesting, forms are nested, and with `ng-repeat`, things still feel pretty sloppy, especially on mobile. Form is quite lengthy and I've split it in several sections, so putting `ng-if` and displaying one section at a time, as well as using `bindonce` does improve performance a bit, but not to the extent that I find suitable from UX POV.

The *catch 22* is that underlying JSON data is unlikely to change, so ideally I'd like to go with the sloppy version in development, but in production I'd like to build/compile the form, and make it load faster.

I know that 3rd party libraries (namely *ui-select*) introduce bottleneck, but apart from using `$templateCache` with `$compile` in `app.run()` section, or rendering the form with templating engine such as [ejs](http://www.embeddedjs.com/), what other tweaks should I take into consideration in order to improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

U can also go for caching of data using IndexedDb or Local Storage to cache the JSON Data which can result to load form more faster.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for spotting that one! I'm using `$localForage` to store bunch of stuff, I completely forgot that I can use it to store cached form as well :)